# Does a paused activity, still receive callbacks from service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

So here is what I am trying to understand.

I have a service like this

```
public MyService extends Service {

    public List<MyListener> listenersList = new ArrayList<>();
    public void addListeners(MyListeners mylistener) {
          listenersList.add(myListener);
      }
    public void eventAOccured(){
          for ( MyListner mylistener : listeners ) {
               mylistener.eventAOccured();
           }
       }

    public void eventBOccured(){
          for ( MyListner mylistener : listeners ) {
               mylistener.eventBOccured();
           }
       }

}
```

And here is my MyListener Interface which activities

```
 public Interface MyListener {
     public eventAOccured();
     public eventBOccured();
}
```

Now we have three activites

```
public Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity implements MyListener{

    public static int myVariable = 1;
    //starts service. For sake of brevity I am skipping this part.
    MyService.add(this);
    //on click of a button 
    startActivity( new Intent (Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
    //Now I know this will put Activity1 in paused state

    @Override
    public void eventAOccured() {
          //Call activity 3
       }

    @Override
    public void eventBOccured() {
          myVariable = 3;
      }

}
```

This is the second activity which is called by clicking a button in activity 1. After Activity2 is launched, lets say eventB occurs. Now If I access myVariable from Activity1, will it be 1 or 3.

After some time let us say, eventA has occured. Now will Activity3 will be launched?

I know an activity being paused means it is no longer visible to the user, but will the communication with service continue?

Comment: what stops you from simply trying?

Comment: I did try, but I am unable to simulate eventA and eventB, therfore my override methods in Activity1 are not getting called.

Comment: try with a callback that you can simulate. For example from B call something in A and see if it works

Comment: Simple answer: yes.

Answer (score 3):

yes, paused activity still will receive the event as it is in the back stack of system and is not destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Override the onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) and  returen STRAT_STICKY. this will restart the service.
You can check following Example.

public class Test extends Service {

```
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e("Test Service ", "onStartCommand");

    return START_STICKY; //It will restart Service in onPause/onDestroy
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    //Do your operation
}
```

}